# positive definite how to prove that LU decomposition is possible

Tags: matrices, matlab, positive-definite, symmetry, lu-decomposition

Given K a symmetrical, square and positive definite matrix, how to prove that LU decomposition is possible without the need of a permutation?

Comment: Can you share your thoughts?

Comment: I thought about this for a long time with no result, while lu decomposition always works using permutation I don't see why there is no need for it with PD matrices...

Answer (score 0):

Because the matrix is symmetric, $U$ can be set as $L^T$. Then the LU decomposition becomes a Cholesky decomposition, for which [explicit formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Computation) showing possibility when the matrix is also positive definite exist.

Comment: I don't want my solution to depend on Cholesky

Comment: @clark_smith You have to.

Comment: just general questions, If I was asked to prove that LDLt decomposition is possible without permutation is it good to start proving that LU  decomposition is possible without permutation?

Comment: @clark_smith Yes.